# What to use as the parent in insertBefore()

Tags: javascript, html

This is the paragraph I am trying to work with. I am attempting to insert a new paragraph before it using JavaScript

```
<p id="mySpecialParagraph">Well hello there, user</p>
```

Here is the associated javascript, what should be used instead for pId.parentNode.insertBefore on the last line?

```
    var pId = document.getElementById("mySpecialParagraph").nodeValue;

        var pNew = document.createElement("P");
        var text = "This should apperar before the other paragraph";
        var t = document.createTextNode(text);

        pNew.appendChild(t);

        pId.parentNode.insertBefore(pNew, pId);
```

Answer (score 1):

It's fine as is. You just need to get rid of the `nodeValue` after your `getElementById()`.

```js
var pId = document.getElementById("mySpecialParagraph");

var pNew = document.createElement("P");
var text = "This should apperar before the other paragraph";
var t = document.createTextNode(text);

pNew.appendChild(t);

pId.parentNode.insertBefore(pNew, pId);
```

```html
<p id="mySpecialParagraph">Well hello there, user</p>
```